# Error when defining variables within a defined function (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code (I received a name error when running this)

```
item = input("What food???")
def itemcheck():
    if item == "chex":
        cereal = "Yummy"
    else:
        cereal = "Yuck!"

itemcheck()
print(cereal)
```

the error was name 'cereal' is not defined. What error am I making/how do I fix it? What is the correct way to define a variable in your own function?

Comment: You just called `itemcheck()` but you are not returning anything from the function back to where it was called from. In your case, you should `return cereal`

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be more optimized. You can try this:

```
def itemcheck():
    if item == "chex":
        return "Yummy"
    else:
        return "Yuck!"
item = input("What food???")
cereal = itemcheck()
print(cereal)
```

You're defining `cereal` inside of function, not in a global scope. That's why you're unable to access `cereal` outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

### **Using a Global variable**

A variable which is defined inside a function is local to that function. However, if you declare it as a global variable, it becomes accessible outside the function.

```
item = input("What food???")
def itemcheck():
    global cereal
    if item == "chex":
        cereal = "Yummy"
    else:
        cereal = "Yuck!"

itemcheck()
print(cereal)
```

.

### **Using a return statement**

You could make a return statement, which specifies the value to be passed back to the code that called the function.

```
item = input("What food???")
def itemcheck():
    if item == "chex":
        return "Yummy"
    else:
        return "Yuck!"

print(itemcheck())
```

Comment: Note: using global variable is always risky

Answer (score 0):

```
item = input("What food???")
def itemcheck():
    if item == "chex":
        cereal = "Yummy"
    else:
        cereal = "Yuck!"
    return cereal

cereal = itemcheck()
print(cereal)
```

You did not return cereal from the function. Since cereal was declared in the function, unless you return it from the function, it doesn't exist after the function has completed it's call. So you need to return it before the function exits.

Comment: While providing the correct code is good, it would be very helpful if you could also describe in words what the original problem was and how it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def itemcheck():
    item = input("What food???")
    cereal = item
    if item == "chex":
        cereal = "Yummy"
    else:
        cereal = "Yuck!"
    print(cereal)

itemcheck()
```